# Unable to login on my machine with right password

Tags: 16.04, login, password

> Even though I entered the right password to my machine I'm unable to
>   login.

**Issue** 
I start my machine and for the first time I'm able to login with my password.
Now I lock my machine or I suspend my laptop and try to login again. Then the Incorrect Password Issue appears.

 Even though the password is correct I'm not able to login.

**Temprorary Solution**
Whenever I switch the user and login with same user then I'm able to login or I restart the machine.

Has anybody, encountered this Issue? And are there any permanent solution?

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
**Machine:** Lenovo ideapad 300

Comment: YES! I just started having this problem last week. I don't have a solution yet. I am running 16.04 LTS, on a Toshiba Satellite. It seems to have started at the same time I solved some OTHER problems with returning from Suspend mode (keyboard and touchpad not working) by editing the grub settings.

Comment: Maybe a keymap issue? Try to switch to a _tty_ with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` and then instead of entering your username, type your password to see if all characters are ok.

Comment: @dgonzalez makes a good point but switching to a virtual console with Ctrl+Alt+F1 to try the password there won't help because the console may have a different keyboard layout. What you should do is verify that the correct keyboard layout setting appears on the lock screen. It's typically somewhere at the top or bottom or near the password entry field.

Comment: @DavidFoerster you are right. Try login in from terminal and changing the password to something simplier like _this1is2my3temp4passwd_ and then try to log in from X. _Hope it helps_.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You mean the En box that shows English (US)?

Comment: @dgonzalez This is not liable to help in my experience of this question, as the password is already just a few plain undecorated lowercase letters.

Comment: Also, in my case anyway, it seems to eventually work to just keep trying the same (simple, definitely being typed the right way) password.

Comment: @Dronz: Yes, exactly. Sorry if my description was unclear. I don't use LightDM for the lock screen so I don't know the exact position of the keyboard layout switch.

Comment: Guys I tried what you suggested. The keymap is same, language is same but the same Incorrect Password issue appears again and again

Comment: Do you get the same result with a different keyboard?

Comment: @TechJhola Have you tried reconfiguring lightdm?  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` !?

Comment: @TechJhola if you create a new user, does the new user also have this issue?

Comment: Perhaps the numlock key gets toggled.  It's difficult to tell what state it's in if the laptop does not have an led for numlock.  Lower case uiojklm all get changed to numbers if your keyboard does not have a separate keypad.

Comment: Just had a similar problem. I figured out my keyboard layout was set to englisch at the lock screen (you can change that at the top right corner).
Might have switched during an update.

Answer (score 0):

Though this issue was reported 2 years back, I faced the same issue today even though I enter the correct password not able to login. sharing the resolution details for my case.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Error: Invalid Password, please try again.

Solution: My password had one capital letter and I was entering the same using shift from mac machine connecting to ubuntu vm and it was failing. Then turned on the Caps Lock enter that one char and turned off the Caps Lock to enter the rest of the chars in my password. It worked!

Hope it helps someone!

Regards,

Fairoz

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me.
In my case, i was trying to connect to a remote vm via ssh.
Terminal was asking me the password to authorize sudo command but i was entering the remote vm password. Took 5 mins to realize terminal asking me the pw of my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Ubuntu 16.04 is no longer supported, so this question may be closed. Make sure the keyboard layout is right. Try opening a terminal using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F3` and see if you can login. I didn't understand the temporary solution, it's confusing.